# CakePHP Auth Component, function allow with parameter "*" doesn't work

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-model

I'm a beginner on cakePHP and I have a problem with Auth Component.
The function allow of Auth doesn't work for permission of all (*). The code is this:

```
    <?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {



    public $components = array(
        'ACL',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {                
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }

}
```

All actions redirecting to the login action. The function allow really doesn't work as planned.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Also see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html#authcomponent

Comment: Then re-read my first two comments, especially, the second :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem... I used the function with parameter empty. It worked

```
    <?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {



    public $components = array(
        'ACL',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {                
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: This was changed to the empty `$this->Auth->allow()` in CakePHP version 2.4x.